# YouTube url extractor with Android player. HD videos stuffer and buffers even on fast internet

Tags: php, android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, youtube-data-api

We are facing challenges in the YouTube player. HD videos stuffer and buffers even on fast internet. All videos that result from search "HD videos" are buffering.

**Implementation how?**

We get streaming URL by using extractor i.e.  [youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor) , [youtube-dl](https://github.com/yausername/youtubedl-android),  of any YouTube video then play using [MD360Player](https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android) . for example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv11L-ZfrSg video streaming URL included in the [yt-vd.html](https://file.io/yAnWQrfCVmak) file. Almost the same behavior in HTML and Android player so you can try HTML video tag.

Check out HTML for observing behavior. Uncomment other URLs

A URL given at the bottom of the HTML page doesn't buffer like the first two URLs. The first two ULRs will buffer every 30-60 seconds.

**Can you fix [youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor) for unlimited bandwidth?**

**What we did so far:**

- Choose lower 360 resolution, reduce the buffering frequency, normal
  videos are playing fine now.
- Try other open source java and Android-based URL
  extractors
- Try different youtube-dl options and flags, also try the
  original python-based youtube-dl
- Study the player buffering
  mechanics, which is fine. The server has some restrictions on
  buffering and bandwidth
- Search for official YouTube APIs to get
  streaming URL but they aren't offering.
- Find out one PHP-based
  downloader and grab a URL that doesn't buffer. Buffer a few times in
  the start compared to our solution. but this solution has some closed source code. And we discussed this involve server so maybe not be a
  viable solution because of the cost and dependency of another server.
  We don't know how this guy is extracting streaming URLs with unlimited
  bandwidth https://github.com/therealvk/DLvidHUT-Video-Downloader

Note: An adaptive streaming URL will be the best solution like YouTube Auto. URLs given in HTML will be expired.

Comment: The downloaders you mention are meant to fetch the stored videos online. Since they are not streamed, you will definitely see stuffer and buffer. YouTube player streams it for you. Can you explain your usecase or problem statement, clarify they question more? what exactly you need it for?

Comment: Usecase: Convert the YT video link to a playable URL without ads like given at the bottom of the HTML page. Which doesn't buffer like the first two URLs. First, two will buffer every 30-60 seconds. But the last one will play smoothly. Tried several times.

Comment: @Qamar The Youtube video link is not for a **360 video** so why play it with a VR/360 player? **(1)** Does a 360 video play ok in HD resolution? If yes, maybe MD360Player just doesn't like HD videos that are non 3D/VR (360)... **(2)** Can HD Youtube videos play normally using another playback system (eg: Android's **videoView** when given the MP4 link)? If yes, then maybe solution is to play the non-VR videos without using MD360Player.... **(3)** It's possible that either your device or the player cannot handle real-time mapping of HD pixels onto 3D surfaces for creating the 360-view effect.